# Find out where bash command definition is stored?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, command-line, sh

I used make/cmake for a project a while ago to build a command line tool, and I thought the binary was only executable while in that directory, but I just found out I'm able to call the command from any directory. This is troublesome because I'm having trouble building a newer project and I suspect this is related.

For example, I can run the command `caffe train` from a specific folder where I built the binary, but it turns out I can run `caffe train` from any folder, which I shouldn't be able to do. I could delete the binary, but the problem is that the command for it is stored and being called from somewhere, but I don't know where.

How can I find out where the definition for this command is stored? I examined my .bash_profile and looked at all the paths it listed, but I'm not seeing a relevant one. Is there another place I ought to be looking to find where command line tools are installed?

Answer (score 3):

Ah sorry I just found out: Using `type command` gives where it is stored. Apparently `whereis command` should also do the same thing, though it gives me no output; for anyone else who has this problem, trying both would be good!

Comment: The `which something` utility asks "What is the path to the binary you run when I type `something`". The PATH environment variable is what determines where the OS searches and in what order when it looks for things, so that's a thing you can Google to get more information.

Comment: (So in your case, `caffe` was somewhere in your PATH. You'd want to fix that, or delete the binary)

Comment: Also consider `which`.  Remember too that bash caches a program's path in a hash table.